# Free/Open Source Test Generator for Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, open-source, code-generation

Are there any libraries for Java that can generate unit tests or unit test skeletons for existing code? I'm looking for something similar to [pythoscope](http://pythoscope.org/). Ideally it would generate code that follows JUnit4 or TestNG conventions.

It looks like [Agitar](http://www.agitar.com/) does something like this, but I'm looking for something free.

Comment: I looked into auto generating tests with Agitar but the tests it generated were not very useful.

Comment: I would be interested in some Java alternative for Pex also. Pex is for .NET and automatically generates tests based on the code.

Answer (score 2):

Most IDEs will generate test method stubs for any class.  I know Eclipse will.

New->JUnit Class
then you tell it which class you're testing and what methods you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

My plugin creates unit tests, it does both JUnit or TestNG tests. Hope you like it.
http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I like how this plugin allows one to select a method and create the test.

Answer (score 0):

Agitar had a free service that allowed you to do this (you had to be prepared to let it send your code to their servers).

If you were using scala, there is "scala check" - but I am not sure how well it works with java source (even though its all byte code).

Comment: Sadly that's unacceptable for my uses (proprietary code)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get TestGen4j running but it looks like it hasn't been maintained :(  Perhaps you give that a try?

Answer (score 0):

from the makers of the google : ( https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/junit/test_case_generation)

### CodePro Analytix

The CodePro JUnit Test Case Generation facility allows you to automate the creation of comprehensive JUnit regression test cases. Given an input class, the tool creates a corresponding test class complete with multiple test methods for each input class method. The tool analyzes each method and input argument with the goal of generating test cases that exercise each line of code

Comment: This is deprecated and will be removed in January 2018