# Best way to automagically migrate tests from JUnit 3 to JUnit 4?

Tags: java, junit, migration

I have a bunch of JUnit 3 classes which extend TestCase and would like to automatically migrate them to be JUnit4 tests with annotations such as `@Before`, `@After`, `@Test`, etc.
Any tool out there to do this in a big batch run?

Comment: Not answering the question, but you do realize that you can run JUnit3 tests under JUnit4 without modification, yes?

Comment: Unless you use Junit3 `TestSuite`, in which case you're stuffed.

Comment: If you keep those JUnit 3 tests around, other developers (depending on your team size) will keep copying them to new tests. And if they need to temporary disable a test (yes, the shouldn't, but sometimes they will need to), they 'll keep renaming it from testX to FIMXEtestX instead of annotating it with @Ignore. So you won't have any idea how many tests are currently being ignored (so how worried you should be). Just take any big project and look for regex "public void \w+test"

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In my opinion, it cannot be that hard. So let's try it:

### 0. Imports

You need to import three annotations:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;`
```

After you've made the next few changes, you won't need `import junit.framework.TestCase;`.

### 1. Annotate `test*` Methods

All methods beginning with `public void test` must be preceded by the `@Test` annotation.
This task is easy with a regex.

### 2. Annotate SetUp and TearDown methods

Eclipse generates following `setUp()` method:

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception { }
```

Must be replaced by:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception { }
```

Same for `tearDown()`:

```
@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception { }
```

replaced by

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception { }
```

### 3. Get rid of `extends TestCase`

Remove exactly one occurence per file of the string

```
" extends TestCase"
```

### 4. Remove main methods?

Probably it's necessary to remove/refactor existing main methods that will execute the test.

### 5. Convert `suite()` method to `@RunWithClass`

According to saua's comment, there must be a conversion of the `suite()` method. Thanks, saua!

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
  TestDog.class
  TestCat.class
  TestAardvark.class
})
```

### Conclusion

I think, it's done very easy via a set of regular expressions, even if it will kill my brain ;)

Comment: The imports can be cleaned up automatically by Eclipse (Ctrl + Shift + O)

Comment: I don't think, that he wants to do this with a bunch of files. And they should be runnable.

Comment: I'd add conversion of suite() methods to @RunWith(Suite.class) @SuiteCkasses()

Comment: the setUp(), tearDown() methods have to be public in JUnit4

Comment: One additional step that I needed was to add @RunWith(JUnit4.class) to my class + import those things:

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

Comment: need to convert the fail(string) and assertXX(...) calls to respective classes, as we do not extend TestCase

Answer (score 39):

Here are the actual regular expressions I used to execute furtelwart's suggestions:

```
// Add @Test
Replace:
^[ \t]+(public +void +test)
With:
    @Test\n    $1
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java

// Remove double @Test's on already @Test annotated files
Replace:
^[ \t]+@Test\n[ \t]+@Test
With:
    @Test
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java


// Remove all empty setUp's
Replace:
^[ \*]+((public|protected) +)?void +setUp\(\)[^\{]*\{\s*(super\.setUp\(\);)?\s*\}\n([ \t]*\n)?
With nothing
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java

// Add @Before to all setUp's
Replace:
^([ \t]+@Override\n)?[ \t]+((public|protected) +)?(void +setUp\(\))
With:
    @Before\n    public void setUp()
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java

// Remove double @Before's on already @Before annotated files
Replace:
^[ \t]+@Before\n[ \t]+@Before
With:
    @Before
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java


// Remove all empty tearDown's
Replace:
^[ \*]+((public|protected) +)?void +tearDown\(\)[^\{]*\{\s*(super\.tearDown\(\);)?\s*\}\n([ \t]*\n)?
With nothing
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java

// Add @After to all tearDown's
Replace:
^([ \t]+@Override\n)?[ \t]+((public|protected) +)?(void +tearDown\(\))
With:
    @After\n    public void tearDown()
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java

// Remove double @After's on already @After annotated files
Replace:
^[ \t]+@After\n[ \t]+@After
With:
    @After
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java


// Remove old imports, add new imports
Replace:
^([ \t]*import[ \t]+junit\.framework\.Assert;\n)?[ \t]*import[ \t]+junit\.framework\.TestCase;
With:
import org.junit.After;\nimport org.junit.Before;\nimport org.junit.Test;\nimport static org.junit.Assert.*;
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java


// Remove all extends TestCase
Replace:
[ \t]+extends[ \t]+TestCase[ \t]+\{
With:
 {
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
File name filter:
*Test.java



// Look for import junit.framework;
Find:
import junit\.framework
Manually fix
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on


// Look for ignored tests (FIXME, disabled, ...)
Find:
public[ \t]+void[ \t]+\w+test
Manually fix
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on


// Look for dummy/empty tests
Find:
public[ \t]+void[ \t]+test[\w\d]*\(\s*\)\s*\{\s*(//[^\n]*)?\s*\}
Manually fix
Regular Expression: on
Case sensitive: on
```

Note: it's important to do them in the order shown above.

Comment: Is there a way to run this?

Comment: Yes. In IntelliJ, do "Replace in path" (ctrl-shift-r) and fill in that dialog for each of these. For those that need to be done manually, use "Find in path" (ctrl-shift-f).

Comment: [Same question for JUnit 4 to JUnit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242083/how-to-automatically-migrate-from-junit-4-to-junit-5)

Answer (score 6):

We are in the middle of migrating a reasonably large code base to JUnit4. Since this is the second time I'm doing a migration such as this, I decided to save the code somewhere:

https://github.com/FranciscoBorges/junit3ToJunit4

It deals with more corner cases than the ones enumerated in answers above. Such as:

- calls to `TestCase.setUp()` and `TestCase.tearDown()`
- calls to `TestCase(String)` constructor within a sub-class constructor
- calls to `TestCase.assert*` methods that moved to `Assert`.
- fixing package names `junit.framework` to `org.junit`
- etc

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a tool that would do this at the moment - I'd expect Eclipse to provide some plugin fairly shortly - but you could knock up a simple source tree exploring Java class that would do it for you if you only want to do a basic conversion. I had to write something similar to automatically generate skeleton test cases for a legacy application so I've got a fair amount of the support code already. You're welcome to use it.

Comment: Do you use java6 AST feature or eclipse AST ? Anyway, I am interested also: may be you may consider making this question a 'code-challenge' and publish your anonymized code on DZones ? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190007 for an example of 'code-chalenge')

Answer (score 3):

There are, to my best knowledge, no available migration tools (yet). What I know is this:

- Last year, at OOPSLA in Nashville, was a paper about API migration but alas their tools seems not be openly available. I'll provide the link to the paper, (even though I dare it is of little use for you since it is rather theory heavy): ["Annotation Refactoring: Inferring Upgrade Transformations for Legacy Applications"](http://people.cs.vt.edu/~tilevich/papers/rosemari-oopsla.pdf).
- Above, I wrote "no available tool (yet)" because my student Lea Hänsenberger is currently working on an auotmated API migration from, not onyl, JUnit 4 a to JExample, but also from JUnit 3 to JUnit 4. Please [follow JExample on Twitter](http://twitter.com/jexample) to get notified when she releases a first beta.

I hope this information was of help for you.

Answer (score 1):

Nice post. I did the upgrade using Netbeans with the following RegEx strings:
(First line search-string, second one replace-string)

```
public void test
@Test\n    public void test

@Override\n.*protected void onSetUp
@Before\n    protected void onSetUp

@Override\n.*protected void onTearDown
@After\n    protected void onTearDown
```

Don't forget to flag the Regular Expression checkbox!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *automatically convert* your Junit3 tests *to Junit4*, you can use the Vogella's Codemodify tool, available at this address:

- https://github.com/vogellacompany/codemodify

TL;DR install and use it as follows:

- get Eclipse if you don't use it already (it's open source)
- From menu: **Help > Install new software**, then paste the update site http://dl.bintray.com/vogellacompany/junit-4-tools/ in the *Work With* field
- Finish the installation, and restart if needed.

Then, you can right-click any Junit3 test class, and select the **Source > Convert to JUnit4** menu entry to convert your class to JUnit4.

[image]

The tool will automagically *remove TestCase parent*, outdated imports, add *@Before*, *@After*, *@Test* annotations, etc.