# Adding @Test to each method after upgarding from Junit 3.x to Junit4.x

Tags: junit4, junit3

We upgraded Junit framework from 3.x to 4.x. and In 4.x, each test method will be recognized by adding @Test annotation at top of the method.

There exists a test class with multiple test methods like test***() (around 250 methods). Do we need add @Test for each and every method? If not, what is the way to make sure all 250 run?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264680/best-way-to-automagically-migrate-tests-from-junit-3-to-junit-4). Pick solution / suggestion which best suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

When I had a large number of tests to convert, I used the [JUnitConverter](http://junit-converter.sourceforge.net/) tool. It performs the following tasks:

- Adding the `@Test` annotation before test methods.
- Adding the `@Before` annotation before the `setUp()` method.
- Adding the `@After` annotation after the `tearDown()` method.
- Adding a static import for adding the different `assert()` methods.

It's not 100% perfect, IIRC, but it does a lot of the work automatically. I used it to convert Apache Commons Lang from JUnit 3 to JUnit 4 some years ago.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, for quick response and framework too. :)

Comment: framework is not working. Any other references? Thanks

Comment: @KiranNunna Sorry, no other ideas. In what way is it not working?