# "folder has not yet been created" error when using JUnit temporary folder in testclass

Tags: java, junit, temporary-directory

I get the error "the temporary folder has not yet been created", which comes from an `IllegalStateException` thrown by the `TemporaryFolder.getRoot()` method. It looks like it's not initialized, but my research showed me that this is usually the case when the temp folder is initialized in setUp()-method. But using it with `@Rule` like I did should work in my opinion. Any ideas?

The test class

```
public class FileReaderTest extends TestCase {

  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

  public FileReaderTest(String testName) {
    super(testName);
  }

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
  }

  @Override
  protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
  }

  public void testCSVWriterAndReader() throws Exception{
    testWriterAndReader(new CSVFileWriter(), new CSVFileReader());
  }

  private void testWriterAndReader(FileWriteService writer, FileReader reader) throws Exception {
    folder = new TemporaryFolder();
    File tempFile = folder.newFile("test.csv");
    DataSet initializedData = createMockData();
    writer.writeDataSetToFile(initializedData, tempFile.getPath());
    DataSet readData = reader.getDataFromFile(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
    assertEquals(initializedData, readData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using JUnit 3 tests which don't support Rules. You have to use a JUnit 4 test for this. Therefore

- Remove `extends TestCase` from the class definition.
- Remove the constructor, the setUp and the tearDown method.
- Add the `@Test` annotation to all test methods (Public methods that start with test.)

should do the migration. Afterwards you have to delete the line

```
folder = new TemporaryFolder();
```

from `testWriterAndReader`.

For more details about the migration: [Best way to automagically migrate tests from JUnit 3 to JUnit 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264680/best-way-to-automagically-migrate-tests-from-junit-3-to-junit-4)