# How to automatically migrate from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5?

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5

In the spirit of [this question from JUnit 3 to JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264680/best-way-to-automagically-migrate-tests-from-junit-3-to-junit-4), are there any list of regular expressions to **efficiently migrate from the junit 4 API to the junit 5 API**, regardless of the code size?

Comment: you can't migrate custom rules anyway..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46882930/1072626, specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055280/1072626).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tooling at the moment is not great, but improving:

- IntelliJ: Migrates most annotations to JUnit 5 versions. Hovewer, does not do anything if your test file contains `@Rule`s (e.g., [`ExpectedException`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html)) as of v2018.2.
- Error Prone: contains built-in refactorings to automatically migrate various JUnit 4 exception-testing idioms (try/fail/catch/assert, `ExpectedException`s, `@Test(expected = …)`) to `assertThrows`, perfectly augmenting IntelliJ.

I recommend the following steps:

1. Add JUnit 5 artefacts to your test dependencies.
2. [Install](http://errorprone.info/docs/installation) Error Prone compiler.
3. [Configure](http://errorprone.info/docs/patching) it to produce a patch to migrate to `assertThrows`, enabling the following checks (the example Maven configuration is below):

   - TryFailRefactoring,
   - ExpectedExceptionRefactoring,
   - TestExceptionRefactoring.
4. Use IntelliJ built-in [refactorings](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/11/intellij-idea-2017-3-junit-support/) to migrate JUnit 4 
   annotations and methods to JUnit 5 counterparts.

I am not aware of any tools that help to automatically migrate `Parameterized` tests, or rules other than `ExpectedException`.

Here is an example Error Prone configuration:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <compilerId>javac-with-errorprone</compilerId>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        <source>${java.compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${java.compiler.target}</target>
        <compilerArgs>        
          <arg>-XepPatchChecks:TryFailRefactoring,ExpectedExceptionRefactoring,TestExceptionRefactoring</arg>
          <arg>-XepPatchLocation:${project.basedir}</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
          <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
          <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

With [openrewrite](https://docs.openrewrite.org/) you can [migrate automagically](https://docs.openrewrite.org/tutorials/running-recipes/migrate-from-junit-4-to-junit-5).

Just run:

```
mvn org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.36.0:run -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-testing-frameworks:1.28.0 -Drewrite.activeRecipes=org.openrewrite.java.testing.junit5.JUnit5BestPractices
```