# Migrating specific tests from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I am trying to migrate test files from Junit 4 to Junit 5
using IntelliJ refactor code -> migrate -> junit 4 to junit 5.

But it only run import optimization and show all unit tests in the project and ask yes or no on refactoring and nothing happens when I chose do refactor.

any one know on another migration tool / plug in or a way to make the migration work ?

Comment: What's you version of IDEA? You can try to download EAP (the cutting edge version) https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ and do the migration there.

Comment: You might find this tool useful: https://github.com/boyarsky/convert-junit4-to-junit5

Comment: Thanks sam, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, seems like the IntelliJIDEA feature is not very ready either => https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179927

Comment: @SamBrannen You should write your link as an answer, so that Ran can accept it.

Comment: Glad you find that converter useful. I'll post it as an answer now.

Answer (score 10):

Jeanne Boyarsky created a tool to convert JUnit 4 based tests to JUnit Jupiter.

You can find it in her GitHub account: https://github.com/boyarsky/convert-junit4-to-junit5

Comment: See also the brilliant built-in Error Prone refactorings to migrate ExpectedExceptions and other exception-testing idioms to `assertThrows`, a rather tedious task if done manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51847402/1792188

Answer (score 5):

Use [openrewrite](https://docs.openrewrite.org/tutorials/running-recipes/migrate-from-junit-4-to-junit-5):

```
mvn org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.36.0:run -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-testing-frameworks:1.28.0 -Drewrite.activeRecipes=org.openrewrite.java.testing.junit5.JUnit5BestPractices
```

which migrates automatically from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 without modifying your code style.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that converting test from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 in IntelliJ 2017.3 is not complete. As suggested by Sam Brannen there is a small application on Github called *[convert-junit4-to-junit5](https://github.com/boyarsky/convert-junit4-to-junit5)* that can do the job.

Just clone the Github repo and build the software using Maven `mvn clean package`. Then run the the application using

```
java -jar \
     <path-to-your-cloned-repo>/convert-junit4-to-junit5/target/convert-junit4-to-to-junit5-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
     <path to where your JUnit 4 tests are located>
```

For further instruction please read the projects [documentation](https://github.com/boyarsky/convert-junit4-to-junit5/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: no main manifest attribute, in target/convert-junit4-to-to-junit5-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar