# JavaFX in the wild?

Tags: java, javafx, ria

Does anybody know of any real-world web applications based on JavaFX?  I'm an experienced Java programmer considering starting a website while I'm not at my day job.  I don't have a lot of expertise on the UI side, so I'm looking for the best way to leverage my existing skills to create something that can provide an awesome RIA experience.  Only trouble is, I don't know of any sites that are implemented using JavaFX, since it's so new.  I'd like to see what it's capable of.

Comment: Hi Julie, did you have time to evaluate the "Automagic unit tests for upholding Object method contracts in Java?" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190007") ?

Comment: We use it in an industrial-strength inhouse PLM solution.

Comment: To use Java to create the user-interface of a web app, I'd suggest [*Vaadin Flow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow_(Java_API)).

Answer (score 4):

Found here quite an [interesting stories](http://learnjavafx.typepad.com/weblog/). Top two listed below.

- [TweetBox](http://code.google.com/p/tweetbox/)
- [TweetFX](http://projectkenai.com/projects/twitterfx)

Answer (score 3):

I think the best example of what JavaFX can do is in the examples on JavaFX.com.

However, it's still early in the JavaFX days thus you will be in pioneer days. Which means there are potential rich rewards to be had, but also - many unknowns.

What I think JavaFX "sweet-spots" are:

1 - If you either have Photoshop skills or are collaborating with someone who is - JavaFX provides the only real platform that lets you take Photoshop and generate a UI. Normally you mock-up in Photoshop and try your best to replicate, JavaFX can leverage it natively.

2 - You get all of the goodies from Java libraries "for free".

3 - Can leverage the UI skills to mobile (those that JavaFX will run on anyway).

However, if you are just wanting to have a Java GUI but would rather wait for more polish on JavaFX - I would recommend grabbing MigLayout & go with Swing on Java 6u10 or later.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few JavaFX apps from the [JavaFX Coding Challenge](http://javafx.com/challenge/index.jsp#winners); my personal favorite is [Music Explorer FX](http://musicexplorerfx.citytechinc.com/).

The new version of [Indaba Music](http://www.indabamusic.com/)'s software was written in JavaFX; the old version was in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion I would not use JavaFX for web. Simply because HTML5 is crushing everyone in sight. Now, I totally recomend the use of JavaFX for desktop applications.