# Success stories for JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Did anyone here a real company using JavaFX for real life applications?
I did a shallow search about JavaFX usage, and found almost no heavy usage case.

Anyone knows companies which actually using JavaFX? I'm really afraid that JavaFX (which is being currently the only somewhat opensource RIA platform) will not survive.

**Update** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471966/javafx-in-the-wild) gives a few example of JavaFX programs (mostly code written for contests). But I saw no commercial users there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ubivent](http://web.ubivent.com/start.en.html) and [DaliReport](http://lodgon.com/DaliReport.html) - I haven't tried either of them but it's marginally comforting to know they exist. Of course, Sun itself uses JavaFX (no surprise there).

Of course, I've also written my own real-world JavaFX application. It's not at the enterprise level, but nonetheless sees many users.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.vancouver2010.com through the Medals or the Athletes pages using the tab called Geo View. Or you can access it via these direct links:

```
**  EN – http://www.vancouver2010.com/olympic-medals/geo-view/
**  FR – http://www.vancouver2010.com/fr/olympique-médailles/vue-de-geo/
```

Answer (score 0):

This press release suggestions  ["Canoo"](http://java.sun.com/javaone/2009/articles/gen_javafxinaction.jsp)

I haven't heard much about people using JavaFX, but it does look like a strong contender to WPF.

Comment: Yeah but it's the first user from '07. I'm not much convinced it has big enough user-base to survive. My only hope is that Sun's semi-monopoly with JVM on the mobile devices would give it some user base.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the shops using JavaFX are listed at javafx.com [here](http://www.javafx.com/partners/).

Comment: But how many of their projects are in JavaFX? It's very vague. See MS "get-the-facts" style site for real usage stories.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen or heard much real, large-scale use myself.

I tried to do a simple little project with it, and it initially seemed awesome, but then I hit a bunch of bugs. This was back when it was still beta though.

Comment: Yeah I totally hated JavaFX before the 1.2 release. Soooo much better now.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the bugs? I'm trying a little project myself, and got frustrated from all kind of little things.

Comment: @Elazar - i'm not sure I even remember any more.  i had started a few threads on one of Sun's forums about a few... I'll see if I can dig them up...